# Walking and comparing contents of binary trees

Tags: tree, concurrency, go

I've written a solution for http://tour.golang.org/concurrency/8, which asks for a `Walk()` function to traverse a randomly generated binary tree, and a `Same()` function to check if two trees have the same values.

Is this solution is the most efficient? (I think that the `Same` function is not the most efficient solution, but I don't know how to make it better.)

```
package main

import "code.google.com/p/go-tour/tree"
import "fmt"

// Walk walks the tree t sending all values
// from the tree to the channel ch.
func Walk(t *tree.Tree, ch chan int) {
    if t == nil {
        return
    }
    Walk(t.Left, ch)
    ch <- t.Value
    Walk(t.Right, ch)
}

// Same determines whether the trees
// t1 and t2 contain the same values.
func Same(t1, t2 *tree.Tree) bool { 
    c1 := make(chan int)
    c2 := make(chan int)
    go Walk(t1,c1) 
    go Walk(t2,c2)
    for z:=0;z<10;z++ {
        if <-c1 != <-c2 {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)    
    go Walk(tree.New(1), ch)
    for z:= 0; z<10; z++ {
        fmt.Println(<-ch)
    }
    fmt.Println(Same(tree.New(1), tree.New(1)) == true)
    fmt.Println(Same(tree.New(1), tree.New(2)) == false)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you haven't completed the exercise properly, since you have hard-coded the termination after reading 10 values. If a rogue `tree.New()` produces a larger tree, you should be able to detect it.